# Want my app to only work on iPhone 4 and above and no other devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Hell all,
I have developed an app that should only work on iPhone 4 and above. The reason is during load time, the app checks the type of iPhone you have and set certain images based on the screen size.

Is this acceptable by apple for me to decide which iPhone user running and set the images based on that?

Also where do I say I want  this app to run on iPhone 4 and above up until iPhone 6+ and not on any other devices such as ipad and etc?

Thanks
Borna

Comment: Your app has to run on iPad.  Even if you set the deployment device to iPhone, your app needs to run in compatibility mode on iPad at iPhone 4 aspect ratio.  Make sure you test on iPad and work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sam B told below, there is no way to specify certain devices.

But with following trick you can get result that you need:

Set your Devices as iPhone in General Tab of xCode proj file. Also if you want 4+ devices set Deployment Target as iOS 7, if you'll keep iOS 8+ it will be 4S+ devices only.

Answer (score 2):

Set your Devices to iPhone rather than Universal under General>Deployment Info and make sure your Deployment Target is set to iOS 7.0.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if deployment target is set to iOS 7 or older

Comment: @Daniel Storm mistake again. if you will set earlier than 7 it will be iPhone 3gs+ :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how the posted answers are considered correct?

The answer to OP question is NO. There is no way for you to restrict access to certain iPhone device (4, 4S, 5, 5S, 6, 6P). If you specify your project to be "iPhone" only in Xcode then technically it will run on all iPhone no matter what the model.

Now having said that you can theoretically make it work only on iPhone 4s or above by setting iOS to 8.0 or above as one cannot load iOS 8 on iPhone 4 or below.

As for the apple reviewers, they will test your app on the latest app device, iPhone 6 or 6p. They don't have time to regression test your app on all possible apple iphone devices.

Does this make sense?

Comment: You're correct there is no way to specify devices, but with this trick you can get expected result.